# jQuery position() returning incorrect, then correct, results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Simple one (probably, knowing me)

I am appending an element to a (Wordpress) website. Standard setup. nothing fancy.

The line reads similar to this:

```
jQuery('[id*="my-required-id-text"]').append('<div class="my-appended-div">A Div</div>')
```

Now, my problem is, that if I was then to cycle through each appended div position using:

```
console.log(jQuery('.my-appended-div').last().position())
```

I - irritatingly - get all top and left positions, exactly the same.
More irritatingly, if I was to do an on click for the class, and put console.log for the position in that, it would show the correct positions for whichever I click.

Why is this? I'm tearing - what's left of - my hair out.

I know I've been a bit vague, but please assume my CSS and the rest of relevant code is correct. I just want to know why the position is detected incorrectly and the same as all other (visually differently placed) divs, yet immediately after running the loop (yeah this is a loop that's outputting divs depending on amount of data fed to it), and assigning the output to another event, the positions are suddenly all console.logged correctly.

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: "Please assume my..." No, you should post all your relevant code (including HTML) so those of us who'd like to help you can get the whole picture.

Comment: Uh `jQuery('.my-appended-div').last()` only gets the last one, there's no iterating there ?

Comment: I haven't included the iterating or any other part of the code as I don't want other things confused with the problem.

Spartacus. "Should" implies there's a rule. There is no rule. I have specifically kept out such information to avoid confusion away from the actual problem. Do not tell me what is what when your what is wrong.

Comment: Best of luck, Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's appearing that way most likely because you're just console logging the .last() div multiple times. The position response you're getting is of course only going to give you top and left positions because position() gives you only the top and left offset from the parent - [see the docs](https://api.jquery.com/position/) - but again, even if you're looping, the .last() div isn't going to change while it loops... it's the same div.

Of course, I could be wrong about this (you haven't posted your code), but I'm fairly confident that's the issue. You probably want to do a loop with a different selector (perhaps one that utilizes *this* as a selector instead).

Comment: I am - in the real code - iterating through each individual div correctly and not just the final one, as each iteration appends a div, which then becomes the final one.

Comment: Right, what I'm saying is that because javascript is asynchronous you can be looping through correctly with the append loop, but by the time you get to the console.log issue the loop is already completed so it's just printing out the last() div x number of times. [See this if you don't understand what I mean](http://www.datchley.name/loop-variable-gotcha/)

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean. Didn't before. Thank you for explaining further. I had been adding ID's during testing but was getting the same result when specifically targeting then sadly. I shall now, however, go back to that testing, to avoid the scenario you described.

Comment: Had a deeper look. This led me to the fix and can't thank you enough. Marked as answered.

Comment: Glad it helped. It's a total "gotcha" and has probably tripped up every developer who has ever touched Javascript, so it's a good thing to learn!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your issue but try to get position after the "each" like that :

```
$objects.each(function(){
  ...
}).promise().done(function(){
  $('.my-appended-div').last().position();
});
```

Little precision : position() depend of this parent and offset() depend of the window.

Comment: I see what you're trying there. I'm getting jQuery.each(...).promise is not a function.